# writing data into mysql with mysqli_real_escape_string() but without &

Tags: php, mysqli

iam using this code below, but the character "&" will not be inserted into the db, also when i copy/paste some text from other pages and put it into the db the text ends for example in the middle of the text, dont know why, i tried also addslashes() and htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities().

i read mysqli_real_escape_string() is againt SQL injection attacks and htmlspecialchars() against XSS attachs, should i also combine them ?

```
$beschreibung = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['beschreibung']);
```

Comment: "not inserted" HOW? you get an error if it's present? it become some other char? and no, escape_string is NOT enough to prevent all forms of sql injection, and htmlspecialchars has absolutely NOTHING to do with sql

Comment: you don't want "&" to store in db or you want to know how to secure your script from sql injection or xss

Comment: @MarcB My guess is that the query string is being terminated before expected. That said, when the `&` symbol pops up, it's not being treated as a string, but a command for `and`

Comment: sure,  i want to put a company name like thomsen & thomsen into the database

Answer (score 0):

SQL Injection is merely just improperly formatted queries. What you're doing is not enough, stop now. Get into the practice of using prepared statements..

```
$Connection = new mysqli("server","user","password","db");
$Query = $Connection->prepare("SELECT Email FROM test_tbl WHERE username=?");
$Query->bind_param('s',$_POST['ObjectContainingUsernameFromPost']);
$Query->execute();
$Query->bind_result($Email);
$Query->fetch();
$Query->close();
```

Above is a very basic example of using prepared statements. It will quickly and easily format your query.

My best guess to what is happening, I'm assuming you're just using the standard:

```
$Query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM test_tbl WHERE Username=".$_POST['User']);
```

As this query is not properly formatted you may have the quotes in your chunk of text which close the query string. PHP will then interpret everything as a command to send to the SQL server

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are doing, you can escape indata yourself and add the escaped data to the query as long as you surround the data with single quotes in the sql. An example:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$beschreibung = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['beschreibung']);
$results = mysqli_query(
    $db,
    sprintf("INSERT INTO foo (beschreibung) VALUES ('%s')", $beschreibung)
);
```

To get predictable results, I advise you to use the very same character encoding, e,g, UTF-8, consistently through your application.